# Filtering products by size in django by passing parameter in url

Tags: django

I am working on a django site. I have a product page on which I display products . I am wanting to filter the products based on the sizes available in the product.
This is my url followed by the views.py and models.py:

```
path("products/<str:type>/<str:sort>/<str:size>",views.products,name="products"),
path("products/<str:type>/<str:sort>/",views.products,{'size':''}),

def products(request,type,sort,size):
    sorting = ['category_id']
    if sort == 'all':
        sorting.append('timeadded')
    elif sort == 'new':
        sorting.append('-timeadded')
    elif sort == 'priceltoh':
        sorting.append('price')
    elif sort == 'pricehtol':
        sorting.append('-price')
    prods=Product.objects.filter(category__type=type).order_by(*sorting)
    context = {
        'categories':Category.objects.filter(type=type),
        'prods':prods,
    }    
    return render(request,"products.html",context)
```

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    S=models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,default=0) #example value 2
    M=models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,default=0) #example value 0
    L=models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,default=0) #example value 1
```

I have removed the parts which I dont think is required here:
What I am wanting to do is that for example if I pass **L** as size in url then the products should filter such that all products with L>0 are displayed . Also if a size is chosen such that for that size not a single product has size>0 for that size then I send a message in template accordingly. I tried several ways to implement it but they were inefficient.Any help would be appriciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
def products(request,type,sort,size=None):
    query = {'product__type':type}
    if size and size in ['L','M','S'] :
        query['{}__gt'.format(size)] = 0
    prods=Product.objects.filter(**query).order_by(*sorting)
```

Here I am building a dictionary with queries. Then I am unpacking that dictionary and passing it through `filter()` method.

Comment: What does these two lines `if size and size in ['L','M','S'] :
        query['{}__gt'.format(size)] = 0` mean and what do they return can you explain briefly please. Also what does format do?

Comment: And also what does = 0  means that format out products for which that size has 0

Comment: they do not return 0, it is making a query like this `S__gt=0`, means this query will filter Products which has the size `S` with value greater than 0

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp

Comment: Does this = 0 also work if integer value for that size is negative or will it only format for the ones for which size = 0

Comment: then it will get data only for size with 0

Comment: Sorry I didnt understand

Comment: For example if size passed in url is S and for some products S= -1 then will those products be displayed or not?

Comment: Also Can I send mutiple sizes in url at once with this?

Comment: Nope and No. For second question, I would suggest you to ask a new question as it is not in the scope of this question with more details on how you are using templates and stuff. :)